# Spring fails to return JSON response with null key

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

Below is the code I have written.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getData", method = RequestMethod.GET)   
public @ResponseBody Map<String,String> test() throws IOException {   
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
map.put("key","value");
map.put(null, "Key's Value"); //**This highlighted code causing the problem, if I remove this then it works fine.**    
    return map;  
}
```

When I hit the URL `localhost:8080/myapp/getData`
I receive the following response

> 10.5.1 500 Internal Server Error
>   The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from  fulfilling the request.

Even Spring does not print any server side exception as well!

I want to know the root cause why Spring can't handle JSON response with key as null.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a null key follow this

http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map-null-values-or-null-key

```
class MyDtoNullKeySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object nullKey, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider unused) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("");
    }
}


@Test
public void givenAllowingMapObjectWithNullKey_whenWriting_thenCorrect() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.getSerializerProvider().setNullKeySerializer(new MyDtoNullKeySerializer());

    MyDto dtoObject = new MyDto();
    dtoObject.setStringValue("dtoObjectString");

    Map<String, MyDto> dtoMap = new HashMap<String, MyDto>();
    dtoMap.put(null, dtoObject);

    String dtoMapAsString = mapper.writeValueAsString(dtoMap);

    assertThat(dtoMapAsString, containsString("\"\""));
    assertThat(dtoMapAsString, containsString("dtoObjectString"));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

JSON object keys must be strings according to the specification. Therefore `null` is not allowed as JSON object key. So the reason it fails is because what you are returning can not be serialized to a valid JSON structure.

However Jackson allows you to use custom serializers and you can create one which handles `null` keys. dom farr's answer describes how to do that.

Comment: I understand why it gets failed though Spring should generate exception on server side because It is hard to find. The code which I provide is sample code to replicate issue. In real I had to go through large number of lines of code to find the root the cause.

Answer (score 1):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getData", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    @JsonSerialize(include=JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
    public @ResponseBody String test() throws IOException {   
    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
        mapper.getSerializerProvider().setNullKeySerializer(new MyNullKeySerializer());
        map.put("key","value");
        map.put(null, "Key's Value");    
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(map);  
    }

class MyNullKeySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object>
{
  @Override
  public void serialize(Object nullKey, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider unused) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
  {
    jsonGenerator.writeFieldName("");
  }
}
```

## Note:

By default, Jackson doesn’t allow the serialization of a Map with a null key. and if you have any doubt, please refer this site. http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-map-null-values-or-null-key