# Json to Java object conversion - Failing in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to parse the following object using jackson in Java.

```
[
  [null, {
    "distance": 2272,
    "duration": 580
  }, {
    "distance": 7217,
    "duration": 1393
  }, {
    "distance": 5773,
    "duration": 1061
  }, {
    "distance": 6208,
    "duration": 1170
  }, {
    "distance": 18846,
    "duration": 2686
  }],
  [{
    "distance": 2262,
    "duration": 558
  }, null, {
    "distance": 7144,
    "duration": 1366
  }, {
    "distance": 4803,
    "duration": 801
  }, {
    "distance": 5238,
    "duration": 910
  }, {
    "distance": 17876,
    "duration": 2426
  }],
  [{
    "distance": 7207,
    "duration": 1393
  }, {
    "distance": 7505,
    "duration": 1411
  }, null, {
    "distance": 12375,
    "duration": 2010
  }, {
    "distance": 12809,
    "duration": 2119
  }, {
    "distance": 24868,
    "duration": 3462
  }],
  [{
    "distance": 7481,
    "duration": 1255
  }, {
    "distance": 4643,
    "duration": 831
  }, {
    "distance": 11497,
    "duration": 2060
  }, null, {
    "distance": 434,
    "duration": 109
  }, {
    "distance": 13197,
    "duration": 1657
  }],
  [{
    "distance": 7723,
    "duration": 1326
  }, {
    "distance": 4884,
    "duration": 902
  }, {
    "distance": 11739,
    "duration": 2130
  }, {
    "distance": 434,
    "duration": 107
  }, null, {
    "distance": 12999,
    "duration": 1628
  }],
  [{
    "distance": 20372,
    "duration": 2918
  }, {
    "distance": 17534,
    "duration": 2493
  }, {
    "distance": 25912,
    "duration": 3432
  }, {
    "distance": 13669,
    "duration": 1774
  }, {
    "distance": 13414,
    "duration": 1779
  }, null]
]
```

Am I'm getting the following error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot
>   construct instance of `com.beeline.DistanceMatrix` (although at least
>   one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to
>   deserialize from String value
>   ('[[null,{"distance":2272,"duration":580},{"distance":7217,"duration":1393},{"distance":5773,"duration":1061},{"distance":6208,"duration":1170},{"distance":18846,"duration":2686}],[{"distance":2262,"duration":558},null,{"distance":7144,"duration":1366},{"distance":4803,"duration":801},{"distance":5238,"duration":910},{"distance":17876,"duration":2426}],[{"distance":7207,"duration":1393},{"distance":7505,"duration":1411},null,{"distance":12375,"duration":2010},{"distance":12809,"duration":2119},{"distance":24868,"duration":3462}],[{"distance":7481,"duration":1255},{"distance":4643,"duration":831},{"distance":11497,"duration":2060},null,{"distance":434,"duration":109},{"distance":13197,"duration":1657}],[{"distance":7723,"duration":1326},{"distance":4884,"duration":902},{"distance":11739,"duration":2130},{"distance":434,"duration":107},null,{"distance":12999,"duration":1628}],[{"distance":20372,"duration":2918},{"distance":17534,"duration":2493},{"distance":25912,"duration":3432},{"distance":13669,"duration":1774},{"distance":13414,"duration":1779},null]]')
>   at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]    at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:3750)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:3668)
>     at com.beeline.JsonParser.(JsonParser.java:17)

The classes I'm using are

**JsonParser.java**

```
public class JsonParser {
    private DistanceMatrix matrix = new DistanceMatrix();
    public JsonParser() {
        String jsonString = "[[null,{\"distance\":2272,\"duration\":580},{\"distance\":7217,\"duration\":1393},{\"distance\":5773,\"duration\":1061},{\"distance\":6208,\"duration\":1170},{\"distance\":18846,\"duration\":2686}],[{\"distance\":2262,\"duration\":558},null,{\"distance\":7144,\"duration\":1366},{\"distance\":4803,\"duration\":801},{\"distance\":5238,\"duration\":910},{\"distance\":17876,\"duration\":2426}],[{\"distance\":7207,\"duration\":1393},{\"distance\":7505,\"duration\":1411},null,{\"distance\":12375,\"duration\":2010},{\"distance\":12809,\"duration\":2119},{\"distance\":24868,\"duration\":3462}],[{\"distance\":7481,\"duration\":1255},{\"distance\":4643,\"duration\":831},{\"distance\":11497,\"duration\":2060},null,{\"distance\":434,\"duration\":109},{\"distance\":13197,\"duration\":1657}],[{\"distance\":7723,\"duration\":1326},{\"distance\":4884,\"duration\":902},{\"distance\":11739,\"duration\":2130},{\"distance\":434,\"duration\":107},null,{\"distance\":12999,\"duration\":1628}],[{\"distance\":20372,\"duration\":2918},{\"distance\":17534,\"duration\":2493},{\"distance\":25912,\"duration\":3432},{\"distance\":13669,\"duration\":1774},{\"distance\":13414,\"duration\":1779},null]]";
        ObjectMapper oMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        oMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
        oMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
        matrix = oMapper.convertValue(jsonString, DistanceMatrix.class);
        System.out.print(matrix);
    }
}
```

**DistanceMatrix.java**

```
public class DistanceMatrix {
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, Float>>> matrix = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, Float>>>();
}
```

I saw multiple issues like this on GitHub and SO. But I can't figure out why it doesn't work. Any pointers on what is going wrong?

Comment: using Jackson, `null` is not allowed as JSON object key, you may have to construct your own serializer to handle them

Comment: please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075147/spring-fails-to-return-json-response-with-null-key)

Comment: Its the same error without nulls. **no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value**

Comment: Is this the complete DistanceMatrix class? No constructor (except for default constructor)?

Comment: yes. I want to see if this basic structure works or not. If it works I'll add more properties, getters and setters

Comment: Try to create an instance of DistanceMatrix and Serialise it using `Jackson` and see if the format is actually correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer which worked for me is both derived from the answer given by @dnt and the same question in Google groups and some own experiment.

1. First this line

`matrix = oMapper.convertValue(jsonString, DistanceMatrix.class);`

should be changed to

```
try {
  matrix = oMapper.readValue(jsonString, DistanceMatrix.class);
}
```

So this will properly read the JSON and try to match it to the structure given.

2. Once that is done it will throw

> Cannot deserialize instance of `com.beeline.DistanceMatrix` out of
>   START_ARRAY token

The reason is the distance matrix class describes a JSON object. The input is expecting { "matrix" :  }

3. Thanks to comment made by @ngueno. There will be a null pointer exception if the object is null. But the library can accept null values as object value. Example

For the above class, this is accepted

```
[{"distance":7217,"duration":null},{"distance":null,"duration":1061}]
```

Whereas this is not accepted

```
[{"distance":7217,"duration":1393},null]
```

I'm pretty sure you can handle it differently in Java (I'm a beginner). But I replaced all my nulls with empty object notation **{}**. So empty object will create a map with no key-value pair. I'll research how to store null in *Map* structure. Or if anyone else comments on it I will update the answer accordingly.

Thanks for the contributions guys.

Answer (score 3):

Your `DistanceMatrix` class describes a JSON object that has a key named `matrix` and a corresponding value of type `ArrayList<ArrayList<Map<String, Float>>>`.

You need to either wrap your JSON to look like `{ "matrix": <your actual JSON> }` or specify the type to `convertValue` directly.

Comment: This helped. But the actual answer has more details. Thank you for your time